# Setting multiple variables' value in one IIF() of a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, iif, cross-join

I have a CROSS JOIN query that I am using to see which combination of item quantities yield the best output.

```
DECLARE @last_found DECIMAL(10, 2) = 0
DECLARE @calculated DECIMAL(10, 2)
DECLARE @n_count INT
DECLARE @tbl1n INT
DECLARE @tbl2n INT
DECLARE @tbl3n INT


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl2
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl3

;WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [value]) AS n
    FROM string_split('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20', ',')
)
SELECT n, (n * 10000 * (1 + IIF(n > 1, (0.50/19.00) * (n - 1), 0))) AS price
INTO #tbl1 FROM numbers

;WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [value]) AS n
    FROM string_split('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12', ',')
)
SELECT n, (n * 15000 * (1 + IIF(n > 1, (0.50/11.00) * (n - 1), 0))) AS price
INTO #tbl2 FROM numbers

;WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [value]) AS n
    FROM string_split('1,2,3,4,5,6', ',')
)
SELECT n, (n * 20000 * (1 + IIF(n > 1, (0.50/5.00) * (n - 1), 0))) AS price
INTO #tbl3 FROM numbers


SELECT
    @n_count = (tbl1.n + tbl2.n + tbl3.n),
    @calculated = IIF(@n_count = 10, (tbl1.price + tbl2.price + tbl3.price), 0),
    @tbl1n = IIF(@calculated > @last_found, tbl1.n, @tbl1n),
    @tbl2n = IIF(@calculated > @last_found, tbl2.n, @tbl2n),
    @tbl3n = IIF(@calculated > @last_found, tbl3.n, @tbl3n),
    @last_found = IIF(@calculated > @last_found, @calculated, @last_found)
FROM #tbl1 tbl1
CROSS JOIN #tbl2 tbl2
CROSS JOIN #tbl3 tbl3


SELECT @last_found AS highest_value, @tbl1n AS tbl1n, @tbl2n AS tbl2n, @tbl3n AS tbl3n,
    t1.price AS tbl1_price, t2.price AS tbl2_price, t3.price AS tbl3_price
FROM #tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN #tbl2 t2 ON t1.n = @tbl1n AND t2.n = @tbl2n
INNER JOIN #tbl3 t3 ON t3.n = @tbl3n
```

As can be seen, if the query finds a value higher than the previously found highest, it is storing the combination using multiple instances of `@itemN = IIF(@calculated > @last_found, tbl.n, @itemN)`.

Is it possible to assign all @tblXn variables in one go? I could use a CONCAT, but I think it may slow down the query, as it is a string operation.

FYI - 'n' is a value between 0 and 20.

Comment: Give example data and the desired **end result** from that data. There will be a much easier way of doing what ever you are trying to do but TBH that it is unclear at the moment because you are relying on undocumented behaviour with multirow variable assignment and because of issues like you assigning to `@last_found` using an expression `@calculated > @last_found` and then you using the same expression again **after** it has just been assigned to

Comment: It is also unclear what `@calculated = IIF(@n_count = 10, ((tbl1.n * tbl1.price), (tbl2.n * tbl2.price), (tbl3.n * tbl3.price)), 0)` means as this is not valid syntax

Comment: @MartinSmith added sample data and output to query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using variables for this at all.

This would be much simpler written as below (without relying on undocumented/unguaranteed behaviour of assignment to variables across multiple rows)

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(combined_price AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS highest_value,
             tbl1.n                                 AS tbl1n,
             tbl2.n                                 AS tbl2n,
             tbl3.n                                 AS tbl3n,
             tbl1.price                             AS tbl1_price,
             tbl2.price                             AS tbl2_price,
             tbl3.price                             AS tbl3_price
FROM   #tbl1 tbl1
       CROSS JOIN #tbl2 tbl2
       CROSS JOIN #tbl3 tbl3
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES (tbl1.price + tbl2.price + tbl3.price, 
                            tbl1.n + tbl2.n + tbl3.n)) CA(combined_price, combined_n)
WHERE  combined_n = 10
ORDER  BY combined_price DESC
```

Comment: I did consider ORDER BY, but my actual query has 11 tables, with a lot more complex calculations than price1 + price2 + price3. If I use ORDER BY, would SQL Server write the output to disk first and sort later, or keep this a pure memory / cpu operation?

Comment: TOP N Sort with N = 1 just needs to keep track of the row with the highest values seen so far it doesn't need to sort the whole result set. You only get a full sort if N is gte 100. https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/sorting-row-goals-and-the-top-100-problem.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
SELECT n_count, calculated, last_found,
       IIF(flag = 1, tbl1.n, @tbl1n) AS tbl1n,
       IIF(flag = 1, tbl2.n, @tbl2n) AS tbl2n,
       IIF(flag = 1, tbl3.n, @tbl3n) AS tbl3n
FROM tbl1 CROSS JOIN 
     tbl2 CROSS JOIN 
     tb CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (tbl1.n + tbl2.n + tbl3.n) 
     ) t(n_count) CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (IIF(n_count = 10, ( (tbl1.n * tbl1.price), (tbl2.n * tbl2.price), (tbl3.n * tbl3.price) ), 0))
     ) tt(calculated) CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (IIF(calculated > @last_found, calculated, @last_found)) 
     ) lst(last_found) CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (IIF(calculated > last_found, 1, 0)) 
     ) cc(flag)
```

Note : You can further assign values to variable.

Comment: This query still checks `IIF(calculated > last_found, ` four times, but is written to retrieve found values easier. Will keep the question open to see if anyone has other alternatives.

Comment: @ShahidThaika. . . You can add one more `apply`.

Comment: this misses the fact that `@last_found` is not static throughout but gets assigned to and then that affects future comparisons against the variable